# Need to add commas to a list of numbers with regexp_replace (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

I'm trying to write a postgres function that will sanitize a list of numbers into a list of comma-separated numbers. These numbers are being entered into an input field.  I want to allow users to just enter a line of space-separated numbers (ex: `1 3 4 12`) and have it change it to `1,3,4,12`.

But, if they do enter it correctly (ex: `1,3,4,12` or `1, 3, 4, 12`), I still want it to sanitize it to `1,3,4,12`.  I also have to account for things like (ex: `1, 3 4, 12`).

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
select regexp_replace(trim(list_of_numbers), '[^0-9.] | [^,]', ',', 'g')
```

If I have a list like this:

```
select regexp_replace(trim('1, 2, 4, 14'), '[^0-9.] | [^,]', ',', 'g')
```

it returns : "1,2,4,14" so that's good.

But, if I have a list like this:

```
select regexp_replace(trim('1 2 4 14'), '[^0-9.] | [^,]', ',', 'g')
```

it returns : `"1,,,4"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your regex to `[^0-9.]+` it'll replace all non-numerics (i.e. , `,`, `,`) with a `,`.

[Try it out here](https://regex101.com/r/qAqVY5/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string on any amount of whitespace or commas `(,|\s)+` and join it back together using commas:

```
select array_to_string(regexp_split_to_array('1 2 4 14', '(,|\s)+'), ', ');
```

Comment: The issue with this is that you'll get redundant commas, e.g. 1, 2 3 4 -> 1,,2,3,4

Comment: That works if they enter it like, '1 2 3 14', but if they actually put in commas like, '1, 2, 3, 14', it adds extra commas (""1,, 2,, 4,, 14"").

Comment: Added commas as part of the split regex, should work now

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to convert to an array using `regexp_split_to_array` then turn that back into a string:

The following:

```
with t(input) as (
  values 
    ('1 3 4 12'), 
    ('1,3,4,12'),
    ('1, 3 4, 12'),
    ('1,3,4,12'),
    ('1   3  4 , 12'),
    ('   1,  2  , 4 12   ')
)
select array_to_string(regexp_split_to_array(trim(input),'(\s+)|(\s*,\s*)'), ',')
from t;
```

returns:

```
array_to_string
---------------
1,3,4,12       
1,3,4,12       
1,3,4,12       
1,3,4,12       
1,3,4,12       
1,3,4,12
```

Comment: Your regex would match many spaces multiple times, f.e. "1____4" becomes "1,,,4".  I thought `(,|\s)+` for any combination of whitespace is a better fit

Comment: This works unless the user enters extra spaces (ex: '1, 2, 4    12').  Then you get "1,2,4,,,,12".